# Need to capture information on an UnexpectedAlertException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I know selenium (used with python here) doesn't support screenshots of alerts/pop ups, but I need a way to capture what is happening with my application.  My script runs with no unexpected errors until it gets to running a larger amount at the same time and continuously (multi-process 11 runs at the same time).  Then, I start getting an unexpected pop up error.  The alert text is undefined, so I can't use that to figure out what is going on.

It normally runs headless, so I tried running it with the browser viewable, but I didn't see anything.  It's hard to monitor 10 browsers when only one is on top.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to debug this?  Or even capture any *helpful* information?

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: undefined
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : undefined}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dang error actually had text that showed "undefined".  Unbelievable.

Anyways, before I figured that out, I found a way to capture the information from the chrome console, so I captured that and printed it to my log file.

`driver.get_log('browser')` where driver is the chrome configuration.

Then, to print it, I used this loop:

```
for entry in message:
    status.write(str(entry))
    status.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. In my case I traced the problem before I got to applying your solution. The app was just asking whether it's okay to leave the page without saving!